# Stuck on homogeneous linear equation $y' ={ {x^2+xy+y^2} \over x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

Given this first-order linear equation: $y' ={ {x^2+xy+y^2} \over x^2}$!

I have to show first that it is homogeneous. I divide numerator and denominator of RHS by $x^2$ to get

$dy/dx=1+{y \over x}+({y \over x})^2$

I then do the regular business with v-substitution until I get:

$Integral{1 \over x}dx$ = $Integral(1+v^2)dv$

After Integration and a some simplification I get:

$v^3+3v = 3ln(x)-3c$.

I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: I think you mean $y^2$ instead of $\frac{y^2}{x^2}$ (In the title)

Comment: @IshanBanerjee thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something went wrong after the substitution. I get 
$$\frac{dv}{1+v^2}=\frac{dx}{x}.$$
On the left we get an arctan.

**Remark:** In this case, we can get $v$, and therefore $y$, explicitly in terms of $x$. However, in general, when we separate variables to solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x)g(y)$, then, even when the integrations are doable, we may not be able to then solve for $y$ explicitly in terms of $x$.

Comment: Thanks, I will double check my substitution. Arctan sounds correct.

Comment: Andre do I substitute y/x with v in the new rewritten equation, or instead substitute y with vx in the original equation on the very first line? I think i misunderstood this whole chapter on homogeneous equations.

Comment: When you solve, you get something like $\arctan v=\ln(|x|)+C$. It would be nice if there were an initial condition. Anyway, $v=\tan(\ln(|x|)+C)$. So $y=x\tan(\ln(|x|)+C)$.

Comment: @Blue Pony You can do both.

Comment: Thanks, again, I was able to produce the result with arctan. My substitution process was incorrect.